# Outlook 2019 doesn't pick up classes value if I apply conditional format, all other email clients including Outlook 365 works

Tags: outlook

if I apply conditon class style won't render

````
<!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="cta-test">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
                <a href="test.com" target="_blank">test</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->```
````

Answer (score 0):

Literally just ran a test with this code and it worked fine.

Three tests.

1. To replicate your issue
2. Mimicking your issue but without the conditional code surrounding it, to see if there is any difference
3. Another inline test for comparative testing.

All rendered as expected.

```css
.cta-test { border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="cta-test" style="width:200px;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
        <a href="test.com" target="_blank">test</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="cta-test" style="width:200px;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <a href="test.com" target="_blank">test 2</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid blue; width:200px;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <a href="test.com" target="_blank">test 3</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The issue could be the specific CSS property you're trying to apply as tables aren't always the best option for applying styles.
What is it you're trying to do with that CTA in Outlook?

Comment: yes it works on all email clients except Outlook 2019, the style is completely removed in test

Comment: That's what I mean. I tested in 2019 and no issues for me. Can you show us what you're trying to apply in Outlook and I can see if it's doable in Outlook?

Comment: thanks for testing but none of the CSS is applied for the conditional part starting <!--[if mso]>, outlook 2019 ignore it completely, renders just plain test, the other tables should have applied style="mso-hide:all;"

Comment: Okay, looks like you might be stuck. Without code to view, I can't help debug or come up with alternative methods.